# XML Schema set a value of attribute of a specific type

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following Schema.

```
<xs:attribute name="level">
<xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
        <xs:pattern value="[0-3]"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

```
<xs:complexType name="var">         
    <xs:attribute ref="level" use="required"/>   
    <xs:attribute ref="name" use="required"/> 
</xs:complexType>

<xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
```

Now I would create an element "pair" that contains two "var". These vars have the attribute "level" set to 0.

```
 <xs:element name="pair">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>     
        <!-- --!>
   </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
```

I have made several attempts but without success. Any help ?

Comment: It might be clearer if you show us the XML you want to describe in your schema. Your schema fragments make no sense, and your description of what you are trying to achieve is very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would not use global attribute declarations, because
they cause problems when you add namespaces to the Schema.

If you want to declare the complex type of the "var" element globally
(because it is used in multiple places), then you can restrict the type
locally and set the "level" attribute to a fixed value.
Note that attributes are inherited in type restrictions, so you
only need to list the attributes that you want to restrict:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:simpleType name="LevelType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
      <xs:pattern value="[0-3]"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:complexType name="VarType">
    <xs:attribute name="level" type="LevelType" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="pair">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="var" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="2">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexContent>
              <xs:restriction base="VarType">
                <xs:attribute name="level" type="LevelType" use="required" fixed="0"/>
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:complexContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

As a more simple alternative, you can just declare the attributes
locally where needed, like so:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:simpleType name="LevelType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
      <xs:pattern value="[0-3]"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:element name="pair">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="var" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="2">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="level" type="LevelType" use="required" fixed="0"/>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I solved by defining a complexType "var" and a complexType "var_i" for i=0,..3. Thank  you !